# Geometric race line - 90 degree angular curve

Tags: calculus, geometry, pythagorean-triples

I am in a process of solving the race curve by driving from outside to inside for $90˚$ curves. I'm trying to solve it with Pythagoras but somehow my theory seems to be flawed. Wolfphram alpha gives error and my calculator seems to give very low results for R2:

[image]

This gives:

$$(R2-R1)^2 = (R2-R1-W)^2 + (R2-R1-W)^2$$

I know there is another solution on this website, but I would like to know where I am wrong.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you explain a bit more? What quantities do you know? What have you tried?

Comment: From your diagram it looks like you have some distances in red wrong. It should be $\sqrt{(R_2-R_1)^2-w^2}$.

Comment: Hi, we know the R1 and W and want to calculate the new R2. Could you explain how i have the distances wrong? I just toke the R2 and subtracted the known R1 and the Width for the rightangle sides.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so you should have

$\begin{align*}
(R_2-R_1)^2&=2(R_2-R_1-W)^2\\R_2-R_1&=\sqrt2(R_2-R_1-W)\\0&=(\sqrt2-1)(R_2-R_1)-\sqrt2W\\R_2&=R_1+\frac{\sqrt2}{\sqrt2-1}W\end{align*}$

Comment: the algebra seems solid, but when I implement numbers such as R1=16 and W=2.5 and plot the equations i get R2=17.4644 and using your equation I get around R2=24.5355

Comment: @Dannychoi When you plot which equations?